# How to process a file containing quotes?

Tags: bash, grep, escape-characters

I know a fair bit about escape characters in BASH. I know that `\` will escape the next character, `" "` will escape all characters except for `$` and `"`, and finally `' '` will escape all characters except for `'`.
So if for example I have text with some single quotes ' in it, I can put " " around it to make it behave like a single text string.
The problem I have is when my file contains both double and single quote characters. Then, I cannot use either type of quotes to escape it. So how do I ask bash to treat it as a single string?

Context: My iPhone's /var/mobile/Library/Safari/History.plist file. It contains something like:

```
  <key>
    <string>http://example.com/folder/index.html</string>
    <string>Title of Webpage which may include ' and "</string>
  </key>
```

I want to `cat` the file, pass it through `grep` to take the first line containing the text `string` and extract the URL from that.
But `grep` chokes on all the quotes.

Edit 1: Here are some screenshots of nano failing to read the file. Cat gives similar output. The graphical file editor iFile reads it as text.
http://cloudrac3r.ddns.net/strange.html
I am told this is what binary files do. I will do some experimenting.

Comment: I'm simply using `cat /path/History.plist` to read the file to stdin (works fine) and then putting ` | grep string` on the end. Grep return nothing.

Comment: Try `grep 'Title of Webpage which may include '\'' and "'` or `grep "Title of Webpage which may include ' and \""`

Answer (score 2):

If you enter the string literally into the command, you can escape the characters at your will.

```
grep 'Title of Webpage which may include '\'' and "' /var/mobile/Library/Safari/History.plist
grep "Title of Webpage which may include ' and \"" /var/mobile/Library/Safari/History.plist
```

Also notice that `cat` isn't needed.

Moreover, it's much better to use an XML-aware tool to process XML.

```
xmllint -xpath \
    '//key[string=concat("Title of Webpage which may include '\'' and ", '\''"'\'')]' \
    /var/mobile/Library/Safari/History.plist
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that grep took a file name. I always piped cat output to it. Thanks for the tip. However, I have a new problem. Reading the file in the terminal using cat or nano or anything returns garbage (!) whereas using a graphical file manager returns the proper xml file. I can link screenshots if you give me some time...

Comment: @cloudrac3r: maybe the file is compressed? `gzip` or something?

Comment: don_crissti suggested it was in fact a binary file; they were right. The plutil command got me the information from it. Another edit will follow after some experiments.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>(Converted edit to answer)</sub>

I used the `plutil` command to convert the plist to proper text since it was a 'binary file'. Once that was done, `grep` had no problem managing the file.